# How Eventbug actually works

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, firebug

[Eventbug](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Extensions#Eventbug) is a add-on for Firebug (yes, add-on for add-on), which is aimed to track all events assigned to DOM elements.

The question is - how it actually works? Since, generally speaking, there is no way, at least as far as I know, to get the list of attached events in W3C event model.

Can somebody who already explored this issue tell me something about the basic idea underneath. Is it redefining `addEventListener` in global scope or something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is using [nsIEventListenerService](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIEventListenerService) which is an internal API available to Firefox add-ons. In fact, it has been introduced specifically for Firebug, see [bug 448602](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=448602).

Comment: I see, thank you. So, we yet don't have any tools to inspect such thing from "simple" client-side.