# Track all JavaScript events in Firefox as they fire

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I have a page with loads of JavaScript events and because of this some of the input boxes have very slow typing.

I found a Firefox/Firebug add-on called "eventbug" but it won't install on my Firefox version (23.01).

I also found a [bookmarklet](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2) that tells me how many events there are on the page.

Is there a Firefox add-on or any other way that allows you to see all the JavaScript events as they fire.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Eventbug actually works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254832/how-eventbug-actually-works)